# If $\int f^n d\mu = c$ is constant for all $n \geq 1$, then $f = 1_A$ $\mu$-a.e. for some measurable $A$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $f \in M(\mathcal{A})$ satisfies $f^{n} \in L^{1}(\mu)$ (so $f$ is Lebesgue integrable) for all $n \geq 1$. We know that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f^{n} d \mu$ exists and is finite then $|f(x)| \leq 1$ $\mu$-a.e. Show that if $\int f^{n} d\mu = c$ is a constant for all $n\geq1$ then $f=1_{A} $ $\mu$-a.e. for some measurable set $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$
\int (f(1-f))^2 d\mu = \int f^2 d\mu - 2 \int f^3 d\mu + \int f^4 d\mu = c - 2c + c =0.
$$
Since $(f(1-f))^2 \geq 0$, it follows that $(f(1-f))^2 = 0$ $\mu$-a.e. This means that $f \in \{0,1\}$ $\mu$-a.e. Let $A = \{f = 1\}$. Then $A$ is measurable and $f = \mathbf{1}_A$ $\mu$-a.e.